# Modify my code - which takes the first sentence of the post and use it as a h2 tag - to work outside the loop

Tags: loop, terms

My code takes the first sentence of a post and places it's content inside a variable. The problem is it works only inside the loop.

I need help making this code outside the loop, becouse I want to use the posts first sentace as description in the header.php

Here it is:

```
<? ob_start();
the_content();
$old_content = ob_get_clean();
$content = strip_tags($old_content);
$match = null;
preg_match('/(.*?[?\.!]{1,3})/', $content, $match);  
$first_sentence = $match[1];   
$the_rest = substr($content, strlen($first_sentence)); 
if ( $first_sentence != '' && $the_rest != '' ){
   echo '<h2>'.$first_sentence.'</h2>';
   echo '<p>'.$the_rest.'</p>';
} ?>
```

One more thing, it would be perfect to keep the posts formating in this code. Any ideea how I can do that?

Ty very much, take care!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get post info outside the regular loop, you can use `WP Query` 
[Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

In your example you can try something like;

```
$firstsentance = new WP_Query();
$firstsentance->query('posts_per_page=-1');  // add additional  query parameters as needed, this will query all posts
$old_content = the_content()';

//do your php stuff here

endwhile;
```